# how to append css file to a child window in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, windows

I created a child window such that when a user click on a button it will open up the child window.

I am thinking of how to style the child window page with css

I attached my css file to the child window but it shows that home.css is not found.

the 2 files are in the same folder.

```
const playRaffle = async (values) => {

const data = {
    ...values,
    raffleId,
    "user_id": 19
}


const raffles = await StakeServices.playRaffle(data);
const res = raffles.data.data;
if (res) {

    const windowFeatures = "scrollbars=no,resizable=no,status=no,location=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,width=600,height=400,left=400,top=250";
    const childWindow = window.open(`http://localhost:3000/agent/print-raffle?playDate=${res.created_at}&name=${res.winningTag}&price=${res.stake_price}&ticketid=${res.ticket_id}`, "_blank", windowFeatures);

    //  childWindow if the child window is successfully opened
    if (childWindow) {
        childWindow.opener = null;

        childWindow.onload = function (res) {
            var childDocument = childWindow.document;
            const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(childWindow.location.search);

            // Access individual parameters
            const item = queryParams.get('name');
            const price = queryParams.get('price');
            const ticketid = queryParams.get('ticketid');
            const playDate = queryParams.get('playDate');


            const styleLink = childWindow.document.createElement('link');
            styleLink.rel = 'stylesheet';
            styleLink.href = 'Home.scss'; // Adjust the path accordingly
            childWindow.document.head.appendChild(styleLink)

            var newDiv = childDocument.createElement('div');
            newDiv.id = 'myDiv';
            newDiv.class = 'myDiv';
            newDiv.classList.add("myDiv");
            newDiv.innerHTML = `
            <div class"inner-window font-sm">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <th>Item</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Ticket ID</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <td>${item}</td>
                        <td>${price}</td>
                        <td>${ticketid}</td>
                        <td>${playDate}</td>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>`;
            childDocument.body.classList.add("child-body");
            childDocument.body.appendChild(newDiv);
        };
    } else {
        alert('Popup blocked. Please allow popups for this site.');
    }
}
```

}

Comment: There’s no ReactJS here. You’re also trying to link a scss file. Scss files need to be preprocessed to browser-readable CSS